# publickey OR password+google authenticator

Tags: ssh

I would like to connect to my vps with my private key when I'm on my home computer. However, when I am on a public computer, I dont want to use a private key. But I dont want to use only a password too. So the solution will be to allow two way for connecting to my vps? The first one, with a private key and the second with both a password and google authenticator. This is the best scenario no? Could you tell me how to achieve this please? Or if you think this is a silly idea, please explan.

Comment: The idea is generally not bad. I'm not sure though that this is the correct plattform. I'd try serverfault/superuser instead, since this is more of a configuration issue.

Comment: I just found the same question on serverfault and stackoverflow. seems nobody knows how to do it

Comment: you mean like: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-two-factor-authentication

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

AuthenticationMethods publickey keyboad-interactive

without a comma between publickey and keyboard-interactive.

Comment: "need to use"? Where? How? Context please.

Comment: @schroeder: I used the tutorial from digitalocean you gave to setup password+google authentication. Then I added AuthenticationMethods publickey keyboard-interactive in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and now I can log in via public key authentication or with password+google authenticator

Comment: Could you edit your Answer to include these things so it makes sense to others?